# React Router: Wrapping some Routes with a component and not directly inside Switch

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to do something like this

```
<Switch>
    <SomeNavBar>
        <Route path="page1">Page 1</Route>
        <Route path="page2">Page 2</Route>
        <Route path="page3">Page 3</Route>
    </SomeNavBar>
    <OtherNavBar>
        <Route path="admin">Admin Page</Route>
    </OtherNavBar>
</Switch>
```

Where I have wrapper component for a routes that are not the admin page.

However the admin route does not render `Admin Page` it just renders a blank page. The other routes work fine.

Is there a way to achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a couple of issues with your example not related to the question which you should rectify before anything else.

The first is that the direct children of a `Switch` must always be a `Route` or `Redirect` - it doesn't know what to do with any other element and will just render the first thing it sees (in your case, the `SomeNavBar` component). The second is that `path` declarations must be prepended with a slash for the router to build them correctly, so `/page1` and `/admin` for example.

With that out the way, here is a somewhat contrived example of how to get the behaviour you are after. For the pages, we are checking from a list of possible fragments before rendering `SomeNavBar` and the correct route. Notice also the `exact` parameter - this is so we don't also match paths that only begin with the specificed fragment, like `/page1foo`:

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path={['/page1', '/page2', '/page3']}>
    <SomeNavBar>
        <Route path="/page1">Page 1</Route>
        <Route path="/page2">Page 2</Route>
        <Route path="/page3">Page 3</Route>
    </SomeNavBar>
  </Route>
  <Route path="/admin">
    <OtherNavBar>
      Admin Page
    </OtherNavBar>
  </Route>
</Switch>
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't knew you can pass an array to `path`